# Category with description and thumbnail

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, categories

I am using the below codes to show all Parent Terms from a custom taxonomy with title and link on a page. But I want to show the parent term description, thumbnail and post count in it too. So how I can get those too (alongside title and link)?

```
$all_categories = get_categories( array(
    'taxonomy'     => 'product_cat',
    'orderby'      => 'name',
    'show_count'   => 0,
    'pad_counts'   => 0,
    'hierarchical' => 1,
    'title_li'     => '',
    'hide_empty'   => 0,
) );
foreach ( $all_categories as $cat ) {
    if ( $cat->category_parent == 0 ) {
        $category_id = $cat->term_id;
        echo '<br /><a href="'. get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat') .'">'. $cat->name .'</a>'; ?>
    } 
}
```

Note: I will give warm welcome to those who also help me to short the upper code more as I think it have some extra stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying after posting here too and I got my snippet and here I am also sharing it so you can also get it. I used the code shared at **[Display WooCommerce Products Categories With Thumbnail & Description](http://www.exeideas.com/2014/11/woocommerce-categories-with-thumbnail-description.html)**. It also shows **Title, Link, Product Count In It, Thumbnail, Description and Custom Text** so this is my solution. Hope you will find it worthy too.